# Span doesn't align with h1 in ie6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I have inside a div, one h1 tag followed by a span tag which are one next to the other, but the span is floating to the right. It works in firefox, chrome, and internet explorer 7 and 8, but not in ie6. In ie6 the h1 tag is bigger for no reason, so the span tag stays bellow it.

Heres the code:

```
     <div style="width: 740px; float:left">

        <div id="article-header">

            <h1><span>Text</span></h1>

            <span class="breadcrumb">Link1 > Link2</span>

        </div>
```

The Css:

```
  #article-header h1
  {
     font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #F2612F;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     display: inline;
     position: relative;
  }
  .breadcrumb
  {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9px;
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin-top: 0px; 

    text-align: right;
    display: inline;
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a live link? It sometimes easier to test that way. However, try one thing for me. It might be a simple white space bug. Just delete the two line returns so it looks like this: `</h2><span class="breadcrumb">`

Comment: The CSS you have posted here, and what you have online is different. Is this CSS from a dev version?

Comment: @Doug Yes, and also I stripped out the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a [CSS Reset File](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to get rid of random, predefined styles in IE6. This eliminates all sorts of "stealth" styles that change  from one browser to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `float:left` on the H1, just use `display:inline`

If you really need to use `float:left` for some reason, then try adding this to an IE6 *only* stylesheet:

```
#article-header h1{
   display: inline;
}
```

It shouldn't affect the rendering negatively, but combined with a float in IE6 the effect is different than a plain `display:inline`

Comment: I fixed it, but it still doesn't work in ie6 :S
I also updated my code in the thread post